# Widget ninepatch - blur bug on android 4.0?

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

I've got some problems with ninepatch images on Android 4.0. Under Gingerbread, the widget used to look like that:

[gingerbread http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/3313/screenshot1321536776703.png](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/3313/screenshot1321536776703.png)

As you can see, the contures are quite sharp.

On Android Ice Cream Sandwich, the widget looks quite different (although the app has not been changed at all):

[ics http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/8602/screenshot2011120217535.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/8602/screenshot2011120217535.png)

The contures are rather blurry, the icons do not look good anymore. I tried a lot to rule out that it's just to a wrong dpi recognition (the devices dpi variable is still the same), for instance copied the resource into "drawable-nodpi". This did not change anything.

Then I recognized that there is one icon which is not blurry. It's the star in the bottom right corner. It's in the same folder than all other images, but it's the only graphic which is not a ninepatch but a normal graphic (iow: there is no .9 in the filename). When I added a .9 to it's filename, this star got blurry too.

So it seems, as if ICS scales the graphics down and up again which ends up in blurry conturs.

Did anybody experienced this too? Might this be an Android bug?

I'm quite puzzled...

Cheers!

Nob

Answer (score 2):

I believe your are referring to this bug:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22387&can=1&q=patch%209&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

It looks like it was already fixed and should be in an update soon if not already for you.  Its NOT in 4.0.1.